# Carousel caption refreshing instead of moving with carousel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel. My carousel captions are pretty big so i wrote them in different files and used

```
 <?php include() ?>
```

like this:

```
    <div class="item">
    <img src="images/alavina.png" alt="alavina" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-captionn">
        <?php include("mycaption.html") ?>
      </div>
  </div>
```

to add them.
I then created a

```
<div id="text"></div>
```

to make the carousel caption appear under the images using:

```
$('#text').html($('.active > .carousel-captionn').html());
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
$('#text').html($('.active > .carousel-captionn').html());
  });
```

The problem is, the div content is just changing without moving with the carousel slides. 
How can I make the Caption that appears in the div move when the carousel moves?
Thank you

Comment: It is difficult to correct without seeing your carousel HTML. I am seeing that `#text` is single element so it won't move along with carousel slide. To move alone with carousel slide, the `caption` should be inside `item`.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo I edited the question and added the HTML, how can I put the div inside the item? thank you

Comment: is `<div id="text"></div>` inside `mycaption.html` or where is it put?

Comment: @LwinHtooKo  no but it right outside <div class="carousel-inner"> just before the arrows to go to next and previous slide

Comment: To move along with slide, you will need to put your caption into `div.item`. You will need to create `div.text` in each `div.item`. And change javascript into `$('.active > .carousel-captionn').parent().find('.text').html($('.active > .carousel-captionn').html());
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
$('.active > .carousel-captionn').parent().find('.text').html($('.active > .carousel-captionn').html());
  });`

Comment: It worked thank you ! @LwinHtooKo